# Convert DataFrameGroupBy object to DataFrame pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I had a dataframe and did a groupby in FIPS and summed the groups that worked fine.

```
kl = ks.groupby('FIPS')

kl.aggregate(np.sum)
```

I just want a normal Dataframe back but I have a `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` object.

Comment: The question title indicates that the question is about how to generally convert a groupby object back to a data frame, yet the question and the accepted answer are only about one special case (sum aggregation). Both the question and the accepted answer would be a lot more helpful if they were about how to generally convert a groupby object to a data frame, without performing any numeric processing on it.

Comment: to get the groups as a dataFrame use something like this ks.groupby('FIPS').get_group("What ever the groupby values you have").

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The **result** of `kl.aggregate(np.sum)` is a normal DataFrame, you just have to assign it to a variable to further use it. With some random data:

```
>>> df = DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
>>>                         'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
...                  'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
...                         'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
...                  'C' : randn(8), 'D' : randn(8)})
>>> grouped = df.groupby('A')
>>> grouped
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x04E2F630>
>>> test = grouped.aggregate(np.sum)
>>> test
            C         D
A                      
bar -1.852376  2.204224
foo -3.398196 -0.045082
```

Comment: Actually, many of DataFrameGroupBy object methods such as (apply, transform, aggregate, head, first, last) return a DataFrame object. I used the method `filter` in [one](https://kenandeen.wordpress.com/2015/06/20/unisex-names-data-analysis-use-case/) of my blog posts.

Comment: It's not a completely normal DataFrame. For example, if you try to call the .info() method on a GroupBy object, you get `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'info' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method.`

Comment: call .reset_index() to convert the grouped indices.

Comment: +1 @hungryMind - *that* is the answer. Re Joris answer - it may be a "dataframe" but it's not normal - you can see it has different column grouping of A vs C and D, which causes plots etc to fail when using as a normal dataframe. It needs collapsing with .reset_index() to make it proper!

Comment: kl.count() returns a DataFrame

Comment: There is what appears to be an undocumented property, `.obj`, which has the original object with grouped transformations applied. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66879388/459863 A feature request with Pandas was also filed which remains open as of this writing: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/43902

Comment: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'reset_index'

Answer (score 29):

```
 df_g.apply(lambda x: x)
```

will return the original dataframe.

Comment: But why is this needed?

Comment: this is still returns DFGroupby

Comment: @cs95 This is equivalent to `pd.DataFrame(grouped.groups)`. The `GroupBy.apply` function apply func to every group and combine them together in a `DataFrame`.

Comment: @C.K. I understand that, thank you. However, my point was more about why we need this method to return the original DataFrame if df_g itself is the original DataFrame? If it's a question of what apply does and how to apply a function to every group, that's a discussion for another post. 2c

Comment: @cs95 Yeap, you're right. I vote for your comment the first time I saw this answer, cause I thought there must be an easier way like `grouped.to_df()`. However, after I checked the API of the `GroupBy` object, I found there wasn't such a function, so I came back to tell everyone this is the easiest way to do that. lol.

Comment: In answer to @cs95, I can only speak to why I sought out this question: This was necessary for me to find how a grouping changed the indices, or after grouping to visualize what has been condensed. Often times this comes up for me due to a heavily nested multiindex or when wanting to perform a group on a grouped df. I suppose this is a shortcut for slicing, but as a new user to multiindex slicing, it has been necessary to find my way.

Comment: I see that today (pd '1.5.3'), one should first add either 'group_keys=True' or 'group_keys=False' as an argument to groupby, before trying above. It is still the right answer IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pd.concat`, just like this:

```py
   pd.concat(map(lambda x: x[1], groups))
```

Or also keep `index` aligned:

```py
   pd.concat(map(lambda x: x[1], groups)).sort_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can output the results of the `groupby` with a .head('# of rows')to a variable.

Ex: `df2 = grouped.head(100)`

Now you have a Pandas data frame "df2" with all your grouped data.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution is using `reset_index()`.

```
df = grouped_df.reset_index()
```

Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html