# Looking for pandas "ungroup by" operation opposite to .groupby in the following string aggregation?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Suppose we take a pandas dataframe...

```
    name  age  family
0   john    1       1
1  jason   36       1
2   jane   32       1
3   jack   26       2
4  james   30       2
```

Then do a `groupby()` ...

```
group_df = df.groupby('family')
group_df = group_df.aggregate({'name': name_join, 'age': pd.np.mean})
```

Then do some aggregate/summarize operation (in my example, my function `name_join` aggregates the names):

```
def name_join(list_names, concat='-'):
    return concat.join(list_names)
```

The grouped summarized output is thus:

```
        age             name
family                      
1        23  john-jason-jane
2        28       jack-james
```

## **Question:**

Is there a quick, efficient way to get to the following from the aggregated table?

```
    name  age  family
0   john   23       1
1  jason   23       1
2   jane   23       1
3   jack   28       2
4  james   28       2
```

(Note: the `age` column values are just examples, I don't care for the information I am losing after averaging in this specific example)

Comment: possible duplicate of [pandas: How do I split text in a column into multiple columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-columns)

Comment: @AndyHayden: perhaps but that question's title sucks; this one is straightforward. (So if only the example use-case needs improving, best to improve it instead of closing this)

Comment: *"A table, stored in a pandas dataframe"* is circumlocution. Just learn to see a dataframe as a table (if that is what it represents).

Comment: The question is slightly unwieldy: instead of doing the aggregate/summarize operation then reversing it, just stop after the `groupby()`, do some averaging on `age` if necessary, then do `reset_index()`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**The rough equivalent is `.reset_index()`**, but it may not be helpful to think of it as the "opposite" of `groupby()`.

You are splitting a string in to pieces, and maintaining each piece's association with 'family'. [This old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-columns/17116976#17116976) does the job.

Just set 'family' as the index column first, refer to the link above, and then `reset_index()` at the end to get your desired result.

Comment: brilliant! I'm still looking at what the combination of apply, lambda, pd.Series and stack does, but it works exactly as intended. thanks!

Answer (score 20):

It turns out that `pd.groupby()` returns an object with the original data stored in `obj`. So ungrouping is just pulling out the original data.

```
group_df = df.groupby('family')
group_df.obj
```

### Example

```
>>> dat_1 = df.groupby("category_2")
>>> dat_1
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7fce78b3dd00>
>>> dat_1.obj
    order_date          category_2     value
1   2011-02-01  Cross Country Race  324400.0
2   2011-03-01  Cross Country Race  142000.0
3   2011-04-01  Cross Country Race  498580.0
4   2011-05-01  Cross Country Race  220310.0
5   2011-06-01  Cross Country Race  364420.0
..         ...                 ...       ...
535 2015-08-01          Triathalon   39200.0
536 2015-09-01          Triathalon   75600.0
537 2015-10-01          Triathalon   58600.0
538 2015-11-01          Triathalon   70050.0
539 2015-12-01          Triathalon   38600.0

[531 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: This is a good hack, but I'm afraid it may not be future proof. I have in mind Hadley Wickham's [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izFssYRsLZs&list=PL9HYL-VRX0oRjeraSIEaY0V_9gx52wdkV) about maintainable code. He warned against off-label usage of functions. The function maintainer might not be aware that end users use the function this way, so he/she might modify the function behavior, unaware that it might break down existing downstream code. What do you think?

Comment: @HanyNagaty Yes - It's of course a possibility. It would be smart of us to request an ungroup() method be added to pandas, which would simply return the grouped_df.obj. They would add unit tests to make sure a test fails if the ungroup() method doesn't work.

Comment: @HanyNagaty I've opened a GitHub Issue on Pandas here. Please support it if you'd like this feature. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/43902

Comment: @MaddDancho Yes I like it and I made a comment there.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a complete example that recovers the original dataframe from the grouped object

```
def name_join(list_names, concat='-'):
    return concat.join(list_names)

print('create dataframe\n')
df = pandas.DataFrame({'name':['john', 'jason', 'jane', 'jack', 'james'], 'age':[1,36,32,26,30], 'family':[1,1,1,2,2]})
df.index.name='indexer'
print(df)
print('create group_by object')
group_obj_df = df.groupby('family')
print(group_obj_df)

print('\nrecover grouped df')
group_joined_df = group_obj_df.aggregate({'name': name_join, 'age': 'mean'})
group_joined_df


create dataframe

          name  age  family
indexer                    
0         john    1       1
1        jason   36       1
2         jane   32       1
3         jack   26       2
4        james   30       2
create group_by object
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7fbfdd9dd048>

recover grouped df 
                   name  age
family                      
1       john-jason-jane   23
2            jack-james   28
```

```
print('\nRecover the original dataframe')
print(pandas.concat([group_obj_df.get_group(key) for key in group_obj_df.groups]))

Recover the original dataframe
          name  age  family
indexer                    
0         john    1       1
1        jason   36       1
2         jane   32       1
3         jack   26       2
4        james   30       2
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to undo DataFrame.groupby, one way is to do DataFrame.groupby.filter(lambda x:True), this gets back to the original DataFrame.

Comment: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'filter'

Comment: In the context of the question it would be group_df.filter(lambda x:True). Worked for me. Has the overhead of copying to a new Dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transform() instead of aggregate.

```
group_df = df.groupby('family', as_index=False)
group_df = group_df.transform({'name': name_join, 'age': pd.np.mean})
```