# Converting groupby dataframe (with dropped duplicate rows by group) into normal dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How do I convert a groupby dataframe I created in order to drop duplicates by a group back into a normal dataframe?

```
df3 = df2.groupby('Organization')
df3 = df3.drop_duplicates('Name')
```

I tried this, but this seems to create abnormal properties that don't allow me to subset my data

```
df3 = df3.add_suffix(' ').reset_index()
df3 = df3.set_index(df3.level_1)
df3.columns = map(lambda x: x.strip(), df3.columns)
df3.ix[:,2:]

AssertionError: Number of manager items must equal union of block items
# manager items: 12, # tot_items: 13
```

Comment: As for me - df3 should be normal dataframe. Show what you have and what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a groupby to drop duplicates, have you considered:

```
df4 = df3.drop_duplicates(['Organization', 'Name'])
```

That will keep you in a normal dataframe the whole time and should accomplish what you're trying to do.

If you want to group and "ungroup" then [this post may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122521/is-there-an-ungroup-by-operation-opposite-to-groupby-in-pandas)