# concatenate multiindex into single index in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.Series` with multiindex:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('one', 'a'), ('one', 'b'),
                                   ('two', 'a'), ('two', 'b')])
s = pd.Series(np.arange(1.0, 5.0), index=index)
print(s)
one  a   1.0
     b   2.0
two  a   3.0
     b   4.0
dtype: float64
```

I want to merge the multiindex into a single index in the following form:

```
one_a   1.0
one_b   2.0
two_a   3.0
two_b   4.0
dtype: float64
```

Is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `map` with `join`:

```
s.index = s.index.map('_'.join)
```

Alternative is `list comprehension`:

```
s.index = ['{}_{}'.format(i, j) for i, j in s.index]

print (s)
one_a    1.0
one_b    2.0
two_a    3.0
two_b    4.0
dtype: float64
```