# Split the value on a cell and update the new column with the split value row-wise using Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I am trying to split the value on a cell and update the new column with the split value row-wise using python. Input and output given below:

Original Excel Sheet

[image: Original Excel Sheet]

New Excel Sheet to get

[image: New Excel Sheet to get]

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122521/is-there-an-ungroup-by-operation-opposite-to-groupby-in-pandas

Comment: Sorry, didn't got much clue. I am new to python. If I get more clear picture.