# Pandas dataframe row reduction/compression (for rows having the same value)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df such as:

```
seed  value
 1      2 
 1      3
 1      4
 2      20
 2      60
```

would like to get a shorter dataframe (df_short) with the average value for same seeds, such as

```
seed  value   
  1     3        
  2     40
```

tried df.groupby("seed"), seems working, though I am getting a DataFrameGroupBy object, which I cannot use as a dataframe. Then from the question [Convert DataFrameGroupBy object to DataFrame pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582449/convert-dataframegroupby-object-to-dataframe-pandas), I tried the following:

```
from pandas import *

df = DataFrame({'seed' : [1 ,1, 1, 2, 2],
               'value' : [2, 3, 4, 20, 60]})           
df_short=df.groupby('seed').aggregate(np.mean)
print df_short        #works as expected
print df_short['seed'] #error
```

`print list(df_short.columns.values)`  should give me `['seed', 'value']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the first three commands (through `df = df.groupby('seed').mean()`)  you will notice that the values 1 and 2 are the index of df and cannot be accessed using `df[seed]`.  We can use [reset_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to convert seed to a column.  Notice, the new index values are 0 and 1.

```
In [48]:

from pandas import *

df = DataFrame({'seed' : [1 ,1, 1, 2, 2],
               'value' : [2, 3, 4, 20, 60]})
df = df.groupby('seed').mean()
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

print df['seed']
print df['value']
print list(df.columns.values)

0    1
1    2
Name: seed, dtype: int64
0     3
1    40
Name: value, dtype: int64
['seed', 'value']
```

Comment: well that is working with aggregate too, but I am trying to get y['seed']

Comment: sorry I was confused.  Do you want to return the values 1 and 2 in a dataframe.

Comment: yes, I need 1,2 vs 3,40. My ultimate goal to plot   seed vs value, with pylab.errorbar,  but errorbar gets confused when there are multiple values having same seed. So I need to convert the dataframe.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your desired output.  Returns a data frame with values 1, 2 in a column called seed.

Comment: well I have to get both columns,not just one. `print list(y.columns.values)` should give me `['seed', 'value']` , not just `['seed']`  or  just `[ 'value']`