# How to create a multi-index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

## Question

There are two questions that look similar but they're not the same question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373660/converting-a-pandas-groupby-object-to-dataframe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582449/convert-dataframegroupby-object-to-dataframe-pandas). They both call a method of `GroupBy`, such as `count()` or `aggregate()`, which I know returns a `DataFrame`. What I'm asking is how to convert the `GroupBy` (class `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy`) object itself into a `DataFrame`. I'll illustrate below.

## Example

Construct an example `DataFrame` as follows.

```
data_list = []
for name in ["sasha", "asa"]:
    for take in ["one", "two"]:
        row = {"name": name, "take": take, "score": numpy.random.rand(), "ping": numpy.random.randint(10, 100)}
        data_list.append(row)
data = pandas.DataFrame(data_list)
```

The above `DataFrame` should look like the following (with different numbers obviously).

```
    name  ping     score take
0  sasha    72  0.923263  one
1  sasha    14  0.724720  two
2    asa    76  0.774320  one
3    asa    71  0.128721  two
```

What I want to do is to group by the columns "name" and "take" (in that order), so that I can get a `DataFrame` indexed by the multiindex constructed from the columns "name" and "take", like below.

```
               score  ping
 name take        
sasha  one  0.923263    72
       two  0.724720    14
  asa  one  0.774320    76
       two  0.128721    71
```

How do I achieve that? If I do `grouped = data.groupby(["name", "take"])`, then `grouped` is a `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` instance. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
data = data.set_index(['name','take'])
print (data)
            ping     score
name  take                
sasha one     46  0.509177
      two     77  0.828984
asa   one     51  0.637451
      two     51  0.658616
```

Comment: Oooooh!!!! Riiiiiight!!!!! OK I'll accept this answer in 9 minutes when Stack Overflow lets me. Thank you.

Comment: When I attempt to use this answer, I get an `AttributeError`. "Cannot access callable attribute 'set_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method"

Comment: @Nate - It seems `data` is not `DataFrame`, but output of groupby - so need `g = df.groupby('col')` and then `g.apply(lambda x: x['col1'].set_index())`

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual question: how to convert DataFrameGroupBy to DataFrame.

Comment: @JamesHirschorn - You are right, title is wrong. Better should be how convert MultiIndex to columns in DataFrame.